# sequelize for psql onDelete: cascade not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I can't get `{ onDelete: 'cascade' }` to work. I have a user table that has many associations (20?) and deleting one user row fails to work because the primary key is depended on in many other tables. I have tried the following:

1. Setting `{ onDelete: 'cascade' }` on the parent association
2. Also including `{ hooks: true }` on the parent association
3. Setting `{ onDelete: 'cascade' }` on the child association
4. Writing a migration to add `{ onDelete: 'cascade' }` to the id type on the users table, but received the following error because removing the primary key constraint isn't possible in order to add the change `ERROR:  cannot drop constraint users_pkey on table users because other objects depend on it`
5. Including `{ onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true }` in the id type initialization in the migration where the users table is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thought the issue was that `{ onDelete: 'cascade' }` wasn't working on my model associations but really the issue was that i didn't first add the `onDelete: 'cascade'` constraint to the foreign key on the relevant tables with migrations.

i was overlooking the simple fact that sequelize.js is an ORM or like an abstraction layer that facilitates interaction with the database. and the sequelize models act as a reflection of what can be accomplished. so first the tables need to be set up correctly/as desired (onDelete needs to be set to 'cascade' or 'sell null' etc) before sequelize can facilitate a request.

example:

//create user table migration

```
  await queryInterface.createTable('users', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()'),
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    first_name: Sequelize.STRING(100),
    last_name: Sequelize.STRING(100),
    profile_photo: Sequelize.STRING(200),
  });
```

//email table (accidentally) created without foreign key constraint to cascade on delete

```
await queryInterface.createTable('emails', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    user_id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      references: {
        model: 'users',
        key: 'id',
      },
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      // onDelete would/could/should be set to cascade here
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
  });
```

//create migration to set onDelete to 'cascade' for foreign key constraint on emails table

```
      await queryInterface.removeConstraint('emails', 'emails_user_id_fkey');
      await queryInterface.addConstraint('emails', {
        fields: ['user_id'],
        type: 'foreign key',
        name: 'emails_user_id_fkey',
        onDelete: 'cascade', // setting onDelete to cascade
        references: {
          table: 'users',
          field: 'id',
        },
      });
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I think i've come accross this same issue; i've tried the above but with no luck. when you say you added onDelete contraint to the foreign key: did you do this on the model definition?

Comment: so first i added the `onDelete: 'cascade'` constraint to the foreign key on the relevant tables with migrations. then i added the `onDelete: 'cascade'` to the associations on the models. i should edit my answer